# Compare values in single arraylist and assign new values to it using java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I want to compare elements in the same list. If elements are not equal increment counter and if they are equal, counter stays the same. I have some issues with getting this correct. 
My list looks like this(these are just made up values for sake of testing):

```
List<Double> sample = new ArrayList<Double>();
        sample.add(110.00);
        sample.add(90.00);
        sample.add(90.00);
        sample.add(20.00);
        sample.add(20.00);
```

and I need to get result as

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3].
```

This is what I have so far and I have tried two different ways.

```
Double count = 1.0;
        for(int i = 0; i  < sample.size()-1; i++)
        {
            Double first = sample.get(i);
            Double second = sample.get(i+1);

            if(first.equals(second))
            {
                sample.set(i, count);
            }
            else
            {
                sample.set(i, count++);
            }

        }
```

This prints:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 20.0]
```

I am not sure how to get that last double compared. I know that I am not checking the size of the list since I have size()-1 but I will get index out of bounds exception.
The second approach is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sample.size()-1; i++) 
        {
           for(int j=i+1; j < sample.size(); j++)
            {
                if(sample.get(i)==sample.get(j))
                {

                    sample.set(i, count);
                }
                else
                {

                    sample.set(i, count++);

                }
        }
        }
```

This will print:

```
[6.0, 8.0, 10.0, 11.0, 20.0]
```

I know I am looping twice but can figure out where to make adjustment.

Comment: Are you comparing only consecutive elements?

Comment: In the first example it should replace 20 with 3.0. I did add else count++ which will increment if they are not equal.

Comment: Try what i posted it should work for what you are saying.

Comment: Sorry I edited it try it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Double count = 1.0;
        for(int i = 0; i  < sample.size()-1; i++)
        {
            Double first = sample.get(i);
            Double second = sample.get(i+1);

            if(first.equals(second))
            {
                sample.set(i, count);
                if((i + 2) == sample.size())
                {
                   sample.set((i+1), count);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                sample.set(i, ++count);
                if((i + 2) == sample.size())
                {
                   sample.set((i+1), count);
                }
            }

        }
```

Try this.

Comment: With this code I get [2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0]...it needs sto more like[1, 2, 2, 3, , 3]. Results should be this because 110 gives 1, first element, next to elements are equal and produce 2 and same is for the elements with values 20.

Comment: Sorry man last time this works i tested i needed to change i + 1 to i + 2. Copy and paste the code now it works! Good luck!

Comment: Now I get [2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0] which is not what I am expecting. I should look more like  [1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0].

Comment: I just had to change +count to count++ in the code above and it works perfectly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need one `count` per `Double`.

Use a `Map`:

```
Map<Double, Integer> doubleCount = new HashMap<>();
for (double d : sample) {
    Integer count = doubleCount.get(d);
    if(count == null) {
        doubleCount.put(d, 1);
    } else {
        doubleCount.put(d, count + 1);
    }
}

// to array
int[] res = new int[sample.size()];
int i = 0;
for(int d : sample) {
    res[i++] = doubleCount.get(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first example you have to handle the last two elements - try this:

```
    Double count = 1.0;
    for(int i = 0; i  < sample.size()-1; i++) {
        Double first = sample.get(i);
        Double second = sample.get(i+1);

        if(first.equals(second)) {
            sample.set(i, count++);

            if(i==(sample.size()-2)) {
                sample.set(i, count);
                sample.set((i+1), count);
            } else {
                sample.set(i, count);
            }
        } else {
            sample.set(i, count);

            if(i==(sample.size()-2)) 
                sample.set((i+1), count);
            else 
                sample.set(i, count);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well it works for me. It gives me this output: [1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0]